# Calculate MD5 hash error with FileNotFoundException while uploading file to S3 bucket with AWS Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

It is required to upload file on S3 buckets.

AWS SDK is being used to achieve upload fuctionality

But when the same piece is running on my Prod EC2 instance, then it generated below error.

Code Snippets:

```
        File fileObj = DocumentUtils.convertMultiPartFileToFile(file);
        User user = userService.getUserDetailsViaHttpHeader(httpHeaders);
        String filePath = user.getId().toString() + "/" + "KMLFiles" + "/" + "KML" + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".kml";
        PutObjectResult putObjectRequest = s3Client.putObject(awsBucketName, filePath, fileObj);
```

```
    public static File convertMultiPartFileToFile(MultipartFile file) {
        File convertedFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convertedFile)) {
            fos.write(file.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return convertedFile;
    }
```

Dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.370</version>
        </dependency>
```

Error Log

```
May 13 19:26:52 ip-172-31-27-27 java[20208]: 2023-05-13 19:26:52.717 DEBUG 20208 --- [nio-9096-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: Test.kml (No such file or directory)
May 13 19:26:52 ip-172-31-27-27 java[20208]: 2023-05-13 19:26:52.721 ERROR 20208 --- [nio-9096-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: Test.kml (No such file or directory)] with root cause
May 13 19:26:52 ip-172-31-27-27 java[20208]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Test.kml (No such file or directory)
May 13 19:26:52 ip-172-31-27-27 java[20208]: #011at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
May 13 19:26:52 ip-172-31-27-27 java[20208]: #011at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219) ~[na:na]
May 13 19:26:52 ip-172-31-27-27 java[20208]: #011at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157) ~[na:na]
May 13 19:26:52 ip-172-31-27-27 java[20208]: #011at com.amazonaws.util.Md5Utils.computeMD5Hash(Md5Utils.java:97) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.370.jar!/:na]
May 13 19:26:52 ip-172-31-27-27 java[20208]: #011at com.amazonaws.util.Md5Utils.md5AsBase64(Md5Utils.java:104) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.370.jar!/:na]
May 13 19:26:52 ip-172-31-27-27 java[20208]: #011at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getInputStream(AmazonS3Client.java:1920) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.370.jar!/:na]
May 13 19:26:52 ip-172-31-27-27 java[20208]: #011at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1842) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.370.jar!/:na]
May 13 19:26:52 ip-172-31-27-27 java[20208]: #011at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1821) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.370.jar!/:na]
May 13 19:26:52 ip-172-31-27-27 java[20208]: #011at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1746) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.12.370.jar!/:na]
```

More observations

1. My upload is working perfectly fine in the local (attempting on my personal machine)
2. S3 acces credeantials are correct at Prod env

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @aled I am getting above mentioned error while uploading file on S3. And I get this only when I upload through EC2 deployed API. I I do the same thing with server running on my local machine, things work fine.

Comment: How do I get correct behavior at EC2 (prod) deployment ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your error log states:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: Test.kml (No such file or directory)

That should be corrected. However,  you should move away from **AWS SDK for Java V1** to the recommended **AWS SDK for Java V2**. V2 is considered best practice. If you do not know about V2, look at the DEV Guide.

[Developer Guide - AWS SDK for Java 2.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html)

To upload an object to an S3 bucket with V2 (and other S3 operations), use [S3Client](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html).

Here is sample Java V2 code that you can use to learn how to successfully use this object. This example performs these tasks:

1. Creates an Amazon S3 bucket.
2. Uploads an object to the bucket.
3. Downloads the object to another local file.
4. Uploads an object using multipart upload.
5. List all objects located in the Amazon S3 bucket.
6. Copies the object to another Amazon S3 bucket.
7. Deletes the object from the Amazon S3 bucket.
8. Deletes the Amazon S3 bucket.

The POM for this example is located in [Github here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/s3).  Full example is below.

```
package com.example.s3;

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.s3_scenario.import]
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Random;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.ResponseBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.waiters.WaiterResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CreateBucketRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CreateMultipartUploadResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.paginators.ListObjectsV2Iterable;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.waiters.S3Waiter;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.UploadPartRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CompleteMultipartUploadRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.HeadBucketResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.DeleteBucketRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.HeadBucketRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CreateMultipartUploadRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CompletedPart;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CompletedMultipartUpload;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Response;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Request;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Object;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.DeleteObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CopyObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CopyObjectResponse;
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.s3_scenario.import]

// snippet-start:[s3.java2.s3_scenario.main]
/**
 *  Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 *  For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 *  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 *
 *  This Java code example performs the following tasks:
 *
 *  1. Creates an Amazon S3 bucket.
 *  2. Uploads an object to the bucket.
 *  3. Downloads the object to another local file.
 *  4. Uploads an object using multipart upload.
 *  5. List all objects located in the Amazon S3 bucket.
 *  6. Copies the object to another Amazon S3 bucket.
 *  7. Deletes the object from the Amazon S3 bucket.
 *  8. Deletes the Amazon S3 bucket.
 */

public class S3Scenario {
    public static final String DASHES = new String(new char[80]).replace("\0", "-");
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String usage = "\n" +
            "Usage:\n" +
            "    <bucketName> <key> <objectPath> <savePath> <toBucket>\n\n" +
            "Where:\n" +
            "    bucketName - The Amazon S3 bucket to create.\n\n" +
            "    key - The key to use.\n\n" +
            "    objectPath - The path where the file is located (for example, C:/AWS/book2.pdf). "+
            "    savePath - The path where the file is saved after it's downloaded (for example, C:/AWS/book2.pdf). " +
            "    toBucket - An Amazon S3 bucket to where an object is copied to (for example, C:/AWS/book2.pdf). ";

        if (args.length != 5) {
            System.out.println(usage);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String bucketName = args[0];
        String key = args[1];
        String objectPath = args[2];
        String savePath = args[3];
        String toBucket = args[4] ;

        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build();

        System.out.println(DASHES);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Amazon S3 example scenario.");
        System.out.println(DASHES);

        System.out.println(DASHES);
        System.out.println("1. Create an Amazon S3 bucket.");
        createBucket(s3, bucketName);
        System.out.println(DASHES);

        System.out.println(DASHES);
        System.out.println("2. Update a local file to the Amazon S3 bucket.");
        uploadLocalFile(s3, bucketName, key, objectPath);
        System.out.println(DASHES);

        System.out.println(DASHES);
        System.out.println("3. Download the object to another local file.");
        getObjectBytes (s3, bucketName, key, savePath);
        System.out.println(DASHES);

        System.out.println(DASHES);
        System.out.println("4. Perform a multipart upload.");
        String multipartKey = "multiPartKey";
        multipartUpload(s3, toBucket, multipartKey);
        System.out.println(DASHES);

        System.out.println(DASHES);
        System.out.println("5. List all objects located in the Amazon S3 bucket.");
        listAllObjects(s3, bucketName);
        anotherListExample(s3, bucketName) ;
        System.out.println(DASHES);

        System.out.println(DASHES);
        System.out.println("6. Copy the object to another Amazon S3 bucket.");
        copyBucketObject (s3, bucketName, key, toBucket);
        System.out.println(DASHES);

        System.out.println(DASHES);
        System.out.println("7. Delete the object from the Amazon S3 bucket.");
        deleteObjectFromBucket(s3, bucketName, key);
        System.out.println(DASHES);

        System.out.println(DASHES);
        System.out.println("8. Delete the Amazon S3 bucket.");
        deleteBucket(s3, bucketName);
        System.out.println(DASHES);

        System.out.println(DASHES);
        System.out.println("All Amazon S3 operations were successfully performed");
        System.out.println(DASHES);
        s3.close();
    }

    // Create a bucket by using a S3Waiter object.
    public static void createBucket( S3Client s3Client, String bucketName) {
        try {
            S3Waiter s3Waiter = s3Client.waiter();
            CreateBucketRequest bucketRequest = CreateBucketRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();

            s3Client.createBucket(bucketRequest);
            HeadBucketRequest bucketRequestWait = HeadBucketRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();

            // Wait until the bucket is created and print out the response.
            WaiterResponse<HeadBucketResponse> waiterResponse = s3Waiter.waitUntilBucketExists(bucketRequestWait);
            waiterResponse.matched().response().ifPresent(System.out::println);
            System.out.println(bucketName +" is ready");

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public static void deleteBucket(S3Client client, String bucket) {
        DeleteBucketRequest deleteBucketRequest = DeleteBucketRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucket)
            .build();

        client.deleteBucket(deleteBucketRequest);
        System.out.println(bucket +" was deleted.");
    }

    /**
     * Upload an object in parts.
     */
    public static void multipartUpload(S3Client s3, String bucketName, String key) {
        int mB = 1024 * 1024;
        // First create a multipart upload and get the upload id.
        CreateMultipartUploadRequest createMultipartUploadRequest = CreateMultipartUploadRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .key(key)
            .build();

        CreateMultipartUploadResponse response = s3.createMultipartUpload(createMultipartUploadRequest);
        String uploadId = response.uploadId();
        System.out.println(uploadId);

        // Upload all the different parts of the object.
        UploadPartRequest uploadPartRequest1 = UploadPartRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .key(key)
            .uploadId(uploadId)
            .partNumber(1).build();

        String etag1 = s3.uploadPart(uploadPartRequest1, RequestBody.fromByteBuffer(getRandomByteBuffer(5 * mB))).eTag();
        CompletedPart part1 = CompletedPart.builder().partNumber(1).eTag(etag1).build();

        UploadPartRequest uploadPartRequest2 = UploadPartRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).key(key)
            .uploadId(uploadId)
            .partNumber(2).build();
        String etag2 = s3.uploadPart(uploadPartRequest2, RequestBody.fromByteBuffer(getRandomByteBuffer(3 * mB))).eTag();
        CompletedPart part2 = CompletedPart.builder().partNumber(2).eTag(etag2).build();

        // Call completeMultipartUpload operation to tell S3 to merge all uploaded
        // parts and finish the multipart operation.
        CompletedMultipartUpload completedMultipartUpload = CompletedMultipartUpload.builder()
            .parts(part1, part2)
            .build();

        CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeMultipartUploadRequest = CompleteMultipartUploadRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .key(key)
            .uploadId(uploadId)
            .multipartUpload(completedMultipartUpload)
            .build();

        s3.completeMultipartUpload(completeMultipartUploadRequest);
    }

    private static ByteBuffer getRandomByteBuffer(int size) {
        byte[] b = new byte[size];
        new Random().nextBytes(b);
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
    }

    public static void getObjectBytes (S3Client s3, String bucketName, String keyName, String path ) {
        try {
            GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                .builder()
                .key(keyName)
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();

            ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest);
            byte[] data = objectBytes.asByteArray();

            // Write the data to a local file.
            File myFile = new File(path);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            os.write(data);
            System.out.println("Successfully obtained bytes from an S3 object");
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }


    public static void uploadLocalFile(S3Client s3, String bucketName, String key, String objectPath) {
        PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .key(key)
            .build();

        s3.putObject(objectRequest, RequestBody.fromFile(new File(objectPath)));
    }

    public static void listAllObjects(S3Client s3, String bucketName) {
        ListObjectsV2Request listObjectsReqManual = ListObjectsV2Request.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .maxKeys(1)
            .build();

        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            ListObjectsV2Response listObjResponse = s3.listObjectsV2(listObjectsReqManual);
            for (S3Object content : listObjResponse.contents()) {
                System.out.println(content.key());
            }

            if (listObjResponse.nextContinuationToken() == null) {
                done = true;
            }

            listObjectsReqManual = listObjectsReqManual.toBuilder()
                .continuationToken(listObjResponse.nextContinuationToken())
                .build();
        }
    }

    public static void anotherListExample(S3Client s3, String bucketName) {
       ListObjectsV2Request listReq = ListObjectsV2Request.builder()
           .bucket(bucketName)
           .maxKeys(1)
           .build();

       ListObjectsV2Iterable listRes = s3.listObjectsV2Paginator(listReq);

       // Process response pages.
       listRes.stream()
           .flatMap(r -> r.contents().stream())
           .forEach(content -> System.out.println(" Key: " + content.key() + " size = " + content.size()));

        // Helper method to work with paginated collection of items directly.
        listRes.contents().stream()
            .forEach(content -> System.out.println(" Key: " + content.key() + " size = " + content.size()));

        for (S3Object content : listRes.contents()) {
            System.out.println(" Key: " + content.key() + " size = " + content.size());
        }
    }

    public static void deleteObjectFromBucket(S3Client s3, String bucketName, String key) {
        DeleteObjectRequest deleteObjectRequest = DeleteObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .key(key)
            .build();

        s3.deleteObject(deleteObjectRequest);
        System.out.println(key +" was deleted");
    }

    public static String copyBucketObject (S3Client s3, String fromBucket, String objectKey, String toBucket) {
        String encodedUrl = null;
        try {
            encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(fromBucket + "/" + objectKey, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.out.println("URL could not be encoded: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        CopyObjectRequest copyReq = CopyObjectRequest.builder()
            .copySource(encodedUrl)
            .destinationBucket(toBucket)
            .destinationKey(objectKey)
            .build();

        try {
            CopyObjectResponse copyRes = s3.copyObject(copyReq);
            System.out.println("The "+ objectKey +" was copied to "+toBucket);
            return copyRes.copyObjectResult().toString();

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }
}
// snippet-end:[s3.java2.s3_scenario.main]
```